# Grab Bing Result From Search Pages

Tags: bing

I want to get the bing result without api , I want to get them direct from bing pages using php. I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use http requests and pares the results to get what you want
you can use regular expressions

example:

$results = file_get_contents("http://www.bing.com/search?q=regular+expressions");

you will find the all HTML content of the page, like you see when click on "view page source"

then apply regex on it to extract the results

Comment: How to do regex please help me i want to get links only

Answer (score 0):

Check out this script: http://www.fromzerotoseo.com/scraping-bing-serp/

in particular the regular expression search which grabs the links:

`preg_match_all(
        '(<div class="sb_tlst">.*<h3>.*<a href="(.*)".*>(.*)</a>.*</h3>.*</div>)siU',
        $result['EXE'], $matches);`

Answer (score 0):

Just use simple_html_dom and do a simple parse. To get # of bing results, you have to find a specific class called "sb_count". If you need links, change the class by "b_attribution" to get all the links. 
You can execute your query as follow by looping through the result page using foreach:

```
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2'); 

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$param = 'Your query';
$html -> load_file('https://www.bing.com/search?q=' . $param . '&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=' . $param . '&sc=8-6&sp=-1&sk=&ghc=1&cvid=e3777d60b1f04c90a3d8f08903433c7a');
    foreach ( $html->find('.sb_count') as $post){
        echo  '<p>' . $post . '</p>';
    }
```

Comment: My bad, I didn't see it was 2 years old question :(